# Selectively masking in android canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, layer, mask

I have a canvas on which the background image if first drawn.
Then another image is drawn on top of the background.
I have a Gradient object that moves across the screen. The Paint used in the Gradient has its Xfermode set as,
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));

The effect works but it is also applied on the background image. How can i avoid the background image from affected by the mask on top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paint will be applied on the whole of your Canvas. As your background is drawn using the same Canvas than the Gradient object, of course using a custom Xfermode will affect said background!

One possible solution would be to separate your background and your foreground in 2 different Canvas objects backed up by separate Bitmap objects, then merge the layers together as one would do in Photoshop. I posted a sample code that does just this on StackOverflow a while ago, here is the link to it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10370828/1350375